# How do I make text content respect overflow:hidden and horizontal padding?

Tags: html, css

How do I make `textContent` of a `<div>` to fit into inner area of a `<div>` respecting both `overflow: hidden` and `padding: 0 10px`, so that only trimmed part of a text fitting the "non-restricted" area of a div is visible?

What I've done so far didn't quite work out:

```css
.my-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div">some really long text line goes inside this fixed-width element</div>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you would like to see and instead what you see?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text-overflow` property along with `overflow: hidden`. You can set the `text-overflow` property to `ellipsis` to show an ellipsis (...) at the end of the text when it overflows its container. Your code should look like this:

```
.my-div {
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 150px;
   height: 20px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 0 10px;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by removing `white-space: nowrap;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

```css
.my-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div">some really long text line goes inside this fixed-width element</div>
```